# appendChild does not add new elements. It just replace the old elements to the new one (java script)

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild, createelement

**data** variable's is 500. This variable has 500 ID of top stories of Hackers News.

and I am trying to add tr elements which shows the title of each ID and rank.

There is no problem if I only add one ID in the loop.

However, if I use more than one ID then the new tr element just replace the old tr element.

I wanted to display 500 top sorties but it only shows one story as you can see.

Is there any way to show 500 stories?

```js
var itemlist = document.querySelector('.itemlist'); //tbody elements
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty', true)

request.onload = function() {
  // begin accessing JSON data here

  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    var temp = data[j];
    var id = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + temp + '.json?print=pretty';
    request.open('GET', id, true)
    request.onload = function() {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      var tr = document.createElement('tr');
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      var td1 = document.createElement('td');
      td.id = temp;
      td.textContent = (j) + '.';
      td1.textContent = data.title;
      tr.appendChild(td);
      tr.appendChild(td1);
      itemlist.appendChild(tr);
      console.log(id);
  }
  request.send();
  }
}

request.send();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table class="main" width="85%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ff6600">
          <table style="padding:2px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="width:18px;">
                  <a href="https://news.ycombinator.com/">
                    <img src="https://news.ycombinator.com/y18.gif" class="ylogo">
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td style="line-height:12px;height:10px">
                  <span class="mainmenu">
                    <span style="margin-right:7px;">
                      <a href="">Hacker News</a>
                    </span>
                    <a href="">new</a>
                    <a href="">|</a>
                    <a href="">past</a>
                    <a href="">|</a>
                    <a href="">comments</a>
                    <a href="">|</a>
                    <a href="">ask</a>
                    <a href="">|</a>
                    <a href="">show</a>
                    <a href="">|</a>
                    <a href="">jobs</a>
                    <a href="">|</a>
                    <a href="">submit</a>
                  </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="pagespace"></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody class="itemlist">
              
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the appendChild method does not make a copy of an item. It allocates on the display the address of an element present in the DOM.

Comment: there is 2 `request.onload ` in your code, this a mess!

Comment: for `TABLE` html element you must use JS `insertRow` and `insertCell`